# Measurement of progress using ObjectiveValue and BestObjectiveValue

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

How to measure progress of (cp-sat) solver?

I am currently approximating with

```
o = solver.ObjectiveValue()
b = solver.BestObjectiveBound()
p = 100 * o / b
```

This works only when maximizing sum over bools multiplied by positive coefficients, so value cannot be below 0.

Any alternative methods?

If one introduces negative coefficients, it seems necessary to floor / cap certain values.

Also, best bound moves constrantly. Shall not one reflect its progress as well (e.g. saving the starting value)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check how mip solvers define the gap, especially the corner case with 0, or different signs.

Note that this is a very poor proxy of the time left in the search.

See this [post][1].

[1]: [https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7085/how-to-compare-the-optimality-gaps-between-a-commercial-solver-and-benders#:~:text=CPLEX%20can%20return%20an%20optimality,1e%2D10%2B%7Cbestinteger%7C](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7085/how-to-compare-the-optimality-gaps-between-a-commercial-solver-and-benders#:%7E:text=CPLEX%20can%20return%20an%20optimality,1e%2D10%2B%7Cbestinteger%7C)).&text=However%2C%20the%20optimality%20gap%20in,(UB%2DLB)%2FUB.